# How to get Ansible playbook ouput in one line?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible we are running a playbook using `ansible-playbook playbookname.yaml`. The output will be multiple lines (like below). I need output in single line.  How can I get that?

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************
GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Why and what did you try?

Comment: Hi. As @030 asked, please add in more info. about what do you mean by not wanting output in multiple lines. In the current state, this qn is very unclear.  We shall consider reopening the post once you clear things up :)

Comment: You probably want to look into callback plugins.

Comment: You could literally translate the newlines by piping to `tr '\n' ' '`  But a custom callback plugin is the way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

That's still a XY problem IMHO, why do you want an output in  a single line at all ? what's the need for it ?

If you can't explain more and wish to footgun yourself by replacing newlines with spaces the use `command | tr '\n' ' '` (you'll probably end up loosing the end of the log).

If your goal if to parse the last line then

`command | awk '/ok=/ { for (i=3; i < 7; i++) { split($i,a,"="); printf a[1]":"a[2]" " } }'`

will give `ok:3 changed:1 unreachable:0 failed:0`

This select the lines containing `ok=` and split each `key=value` field (3 to 6) on the `=` char, thus giving the key as first element of array `a` and the value as the second element.

use `print` instead of `printf` to get each state on separate lines.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if that is possible or not but you can write same command in bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

ansible-playbook playbookname.yaml > output.txt

# Then grep from output.txt what you want

grep -A 5 "PLAY" output.txt
```

May not be good way but will achieve what you want.

Comment: Would work only if there's less than 6 lines after the PLAY keyword...

Comment: (well would work, but not answering the question as it would output the same thing as in the question, which is not what the question is about)

Comment: just an example s/he can grep anything s/he like

Comment: I don't get the point of showing how to grep multiple lines where the question is how to get the output in one line ... For sure it does not achieve what the OP is after